# Pipe to sort and back to main

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork

So i am trying to understand how pipes work in UNIX and i am trying to pipe a text into sort, sort them and pipe them back to main to doo. But when the execution reaches:

Note: The program takes the text file as an argument.

```
execlp("sort", "sort",(char *)0);
```

The program stops and stays still there like its waiting from the pipe something. I know that there must be something with my understanding of UNIX piping.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    int pipe1[2];
    int pipe2[2];

    pid_t childpid;

    FILE *fdin;

    long fsize;

    pipe(pipe1);
    pipe(pipe2);

// error handling
    if ((childpid = fork()) == -1){
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

// parent load file, write to pipe1
    if (childpid != 0){
        char buf[1024];
        close(pipe1[0]);
        close(pipe2[1]);

        fdin = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        //fseek(fdin, 0, SEEK_END);
        //fsize = ftell(fdin);
        //fseek(fdin, 0, SEEK_SET);

        fread(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, fdin);
        fclose(fdin);

        dup2(pipe1[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
        write(pipe1[1], buf, sizeof(buf));
        close(pipe1[1]);
    }
    else if (childpid == 0){
        char buf[1024];
        close(pipe1[1]);
        close(pipe2[0]);
        //dup2(pipe2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        //dup2(pipe1[0], STDIN_FILENO);

        read(pipe1[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
        close(pipe1[0]);

        printf("%s\n\n", buf);

        dup2(pipe2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipe2[1]);

        execlp("sort", "sort",(char *)0);

        printf("%s\n", buf);
        exit(0);
    }

// wait child
    wait(NULL);

// parent read pipe 2 and print
    if (childpid != 0){
        // DOOOO
        //read(pipe2[0], buf, 1024);
        //printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Dead Locked**
[image: Thought Picture 1 Dead Lock]

**Updated**
[image: Thought Picture 2]

**UPDATE: 1**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

//char *message = "This is a message!!!";

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    int pipe1[2];
    int pipe2[2];

    pid_t childpid[2];

    FILE *fdin;
    char buf[1024];

    //long fsize;

    pipe(pipe1);
    pipe(pipe2);

// error handling
    if ((childpid[0] = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    // parent load file, write to pipe1
    if (childpid[0] != 0){

        close(pipe1[0]);
        close(pipe2[1]);


        fdin = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        //fseek(fdin, 0, SEEK_END);
        //fsize = ftell(fdin);
        //fseek(fdin, 0, SEEK_SET);

        fread(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, fdin);
        fclose(fdin);

        dup2(pipe1[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
        write(pipe1[1], buf, sizeof(buf));
        close(pipe1[1]);
    }
    else if (childpid[0] == 0){
        buf[0] = '\0';
        int pipe3[2];

        pipe(pipe3);

        close(pipe1[1]);
        close(pipe2[0]);

        //dup2(pipe2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(pipe1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        //dup2(pipe3[1],STDOUT_FILENO);

        read(pipe1[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
        close(pipe1[0]);

        write(pipe3[1], buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("-PIPED BUFF-\n%s\n\n", buf);

        if ((childpid[1] = fork()) == -1){
            perror("fork second child");
            exit(1);
        }
        // Child of child (sort call)
        if (childpid[1] != 0){
            close(pipe2[1]);
            close(pipe3[0]);
            printf("I AM YOUR FATHER LOOK\n");
        }else{
            printf("a\n");
            buf[0] = '\0';
            printf("b\n");
            close(pipe3[1]);
            printf("c\n\n");

            dup2(pipe3[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            read(pipe3[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
            close(pipe3[0]);

            printf("-SORT BUFF-\n%s\n\n", buf);

            //dup2(pipe2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(pipe2[1]);

            execlp("sort","sort",(char *)0);

            printf("-SORTED BUFF-\n%s\n\n", buf);
            exit(0);
        }
        // wait second child exec
        wait(NULL);

        //printf("%s\n", buf);
        exit(0);
    }

    // wait child exec
    //wait(NULL);

    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    int n = 2;
    while (n > 0){
        pid = wait(&status);
        printf("-SORTED BUFF-\n%s\n\n", buf);
        --n;
    }
    // parent read pipe 2 and print
    if (childpid[0] != 0){
        printf("asd\n");
        buf[0] = '\0';
        dup2(pipe2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        read(pipe2[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
        close(pipe2[0]);
        printf("-SORTED BUFF-\n%s\n\n", buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: **Thought 3**]

Comment: You need to check all of your function calls for errors.

Comment: You're trying to read `fsize + 1` bytes from a file that's only `fsize` bytes, into a fixed buffer of size `1024`. Then you're calling `strlen` on the buffer, which is not terminated at this point. :-(

Comment: You forget to `dup2()` `STDIN_FILENO` in the child. Plus you can't do this properly with only need 2 processes, You need 3 something one to write the pipe, the sort process and something to read the pipe.

Comment: @Stargateur so i need Main and 3 children ?

Comment: @KALALEX Or main + 2 children. You can't write and after read a pipe with the same process because imagine you want write a lot of data. You gonna need more than one write. But the pipe are limited. If you don't read **and** write you will block someday in the write. Here is not a problem but I imagine that is just a test to a future big project.

Comment: @Stargateur so i updated the code please have a look. I use 1 main 2 proc of which one becomes sort and pipes the sort result from sort pipe2[1] -> pipe2[0] main (because i dup2(pipe2[1], STDOUT_FILENO)). Bur when i call execlp("sort","sort",(char *)0); the proc doesn't go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Part 1

In your parent code, you have:

```
dup2(pipe1[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
write(pipe1[1], buf, sizeof(buf));
close(pipe1[1]);
```

This is problematic on multiple counts:

1. The parent's standard output is now the write end of the pipe used for sending information to the child.  That means the parent will have to open a file or terminal or something to write the results of `sort` to its original standard output.
2. When you `close(pipe1[1])`, there is still an open file descriptor for the pipe (the parent's standard output), so `sort` never gets `EOF` on the pipe.
3. You didn't record how much data you read, so you don't know how much data you should write.  You could be writing garbage to the pipe unless you know the file is bigger than 1024 bytes.  You should capture the amount of data read from the file and only write that much data to the pipe.  You should think about ensuring the information ends with a newline.

Since you `wait()` for the child to complete, but the child doesn't know its input is complete, you have a deadlock.  You then have the code to read the input data, but it isn't clear where you're going to write because of the `dup2()`.

- First stage fix: remove the identified `dup2()`.

#### Fretting about deadlocks

In principle, the whole design only works because `sort` has to read all its input before it can write any of its output.  If you had a command such as `awk` or `sed` that can write output before it finishes reading its input, your two-way pipe scheme wouldn't work well on large volumes of data.  The child might fill the pipe buffer (and not be able to write any more to it) while the parent is still trying to write and finds its pipe buffer is full.  Both processes would be stuck in a write waiting for the other to read.  There are ways around that — `select()`, `poll()`, multiple threads, etc. — but they're beyond the scope of what you want, or need, to deal with now.

Also, your program limits the input to `sort` to at most 1024 bytes. That isn't enough to fill any pipe buffer, which means that unless the executed command increases the amount of data it has to write back compared with what it reads in — for example, if you sent URLs to a process that fetched the data from those URLs — then you won't run into deadlocks.

#### Part 2

The child code seems to read the data from the pipe, then launches `sort` (but there's nothing left for `sort` to read), and seems to expect `execlp()` to return.  The code simply needs to connect the correct ends of the pipes to standard input and output, close *all* the pipe file descriptors, and then execute `sort`.  If `execlp()` returns, it failed — report the error.

- Second stage fix: simplify the child process, and make `sort` do the reading and writing.

#### Working code

Lots of commented out bits left behind.  Key error checking added.  For example, check that the command line is correct before doing anything else.  Often, you'd open the file before forking; this time, it is better not to do that.  Report errors on standard error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    int pipe1[2];
    int pipe2[2];
    pid_t childpid;
    FILE *fdin;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    pipe(pipe1);
    pipe(pipe2);

    // error handling
    if ((childpid = fork()) == -1){
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    // parent load file, write to pipe1
    if (childpid != 0){
        //long fsize;
        char buf[1024];
        close(pipe1[0]);
        close(pipe2[1]);

        fdin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (fdin == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file '%s'\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
            exit(1);
        }

        //fseek(fdin, 0, SEEK_END);
        //fsize = ftell(fdin);
        //fseek(fdin, 0, SEEK_SET);

        int nbytes = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fdin);
        if (nbytes <= 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: no data in file '%s'\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
            exit(1);
        }
        fclose(fdin);

        //dup2(pipe1[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
        write(pipe1[1], buf, nbytes);
        close(pipe1[1]);
    }
    else if (childpid == 0){
        //char buf[1024];
        close(pipe1[1]);
        close(pipe2[0]);
        dup2(pipe2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(pipe1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pipe2[1]);
        close(pipe1[0]);

        //read(pipe1[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
        //close(pipe1[0]);

        //printf("%s\n\n", buf);

        //dup2(pipe2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        //close(pipe2[1]);

        execlp("sort", "sort",(char *)0);

        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to exec 'sort'\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    // wait child
    wait(NULL);

    // parent read pipe 2 and print
    if (childpid != 0){
        char buf[1024];
        int nbytes;
        while ((nbytes = read(pipe2[0], buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
            printf("%.*s", nbytes, buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note the careful trapping of sizes on both read operations.

Consider an input file:

```
Harlequin
Preposterous
Animagus
Zealot
Queensbury Rules
Quaternion
Hedwig
Tensor
Tenser
```

The output I get is:

```
Animagus
Harlequin
Hedwig
Preposterous
Quaternion
Queensbury Rules
Tenser
Tensor
Zealot
```

This looks correct to me.

Comment: Thank you that is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is to have the parent that open the file and write it to a pipe. In the same time we have a child that create a second pipe and read it. And again in the same time we have a second child that exec sort.

We need 2 child and 2 pipe. The first parent wait the first child and the first child wait the second child.

I don't know if it's perfect because I can't test and this king of thing is very complex:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

static int wait_and_return(pid_t pid) {
  int status;
  if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1) {
    perror("waitpid()");
    return 1;
  }
  return status;
}

static pid_t create_pipe_and_fork(int fd_pipe[2]) {
  if (pipe(fd_pipe) == -1) {
    perror("pipe()");
    return -1;
  }

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid == -1) {
    close(fd_pipe[0]);
    close(fd_pipe[1]);
    perror("fork()");
    return -1;
  }

  return pid;
}

static int exec_sort(int fd_in, int fd_out) {
  if (dup2(fd_in, STDIN_FILENO) == -1 || dup2(fd_out, STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
    close(fd_in);
    close(fd_out);
    perror("dup2()");
    return 1;
  }

  close(fd_in);
  close(fd_out);

  execlp("sort", "sort", (char *)NULL);
  perror("execlp()");
  return 1;
}

static int child(int fd) {
  int fd_pipe[2];
  pid_t pid = create_pipe_and_fork(fd_pipe);
  if (pid == -1) {
    close(fd);
    return 1;
  }

  if (pid != 0) {
    close(fd);
    close(fd_pipe[1]);
    char buf[4048];
    ssize_t ret;
    while ((ret = read(fd_pipe[0], buf, sizeof buf)) > 0) {
      if (ret > INT_MAX) {
        close(fd_pipe[0]);
        wait_and_return(pid);
        return 1;
      }
      printf("%.*s", (int)ret, buf);
    }

    close(fd_pipe[0]);

    return wait_and_return(pid);
  } else {
    close(fd_pipe[0]);

    return exec_sort(fd, fd_pipe[1]);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "wrong argument\n");
    return 1;
  }

  int fd_pipe[2];
  pid_t pid = create_pipe_and_fork(fd_pipe);
  if (pid == -1) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (pid != 0) {
    close(fd_pipe[0]);

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
      perror("fopen():");
      close(fd_pipe[1]);
      wait_and_return(pid);
      return 1;
    }

    char buf[4048];
    size_t ret;
    while ((ret = fread(buf, sizeof *buf, sizeof buf / sizeof *buf, file))) {
      write(fd_pipe[1], buf, ret);
    }
    fclose(file);

    close(fd_pipe[1]);

    return wait_and_return(pid);
  } else {
    close(fd_pipe[1]);

    return child(fd_pipe[0]);
  }
}
```

It possible to inverse the role of main and the last child so the main will read the result and the child will open the file. I let you try.

Comment: You are correct too it's just that Jonathan shows whats wrong with what i programmed, thank you anyways yours is much cleaner.